# DFS synchronisation over slow internet connection

Tags: windows-server-2012, dfs, dfs-r

I am configuring DFS replication on 2 servers connected over a VPN. The VPN is over a ADSL line with 0.06mb upload speed.

server1 - 192.168.1.2
server2 - 192.168.2.2

Both servers can see each other over the VPN by name, however if I was to set up DFS the initial sync will be moving 120GB of data, which will take far too long.

If I was to take server2 over to server1's local network, plug it in and do the initial sync over the local LAN (gigabit), then take the server back to its site, would DFS just continue to replicate the drives?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if u were using dhcp for both server within domain, it could work i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work no problem.

Both DFS Namespaces and Replication are based on hostname, so as long as they can communicate and resolve that way, you're all set.

Also, using DFS for the initial sync will work but will probably take longer than pre-seeding the data manually. I'd suggest you robocopy the data  while they're on the same LAN, then let DFS-R keep them in sync. You can find more information, and a how-to guide [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495052.aspx).